# How to close every interactive PowerShell session?

Tags: powershell, session

Is there a way to exit every interactive PowerShell session created by `Enter-PSSession` in PowerShell?

I tried something like
:

```
Get-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential | Exit-PSSession
```

or

```
Get-PSSession -ComputerName "my computer name" -Credential username@domain.local | foreach { Exit-PSSession $_ }
```

But does not seem to be right...

```
Exit-PSSession : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take
pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
[...]
```

Example of `Get-PSSession`:

```
PS C:\Users\username> Get-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential

 Id Name            ComputerName    ComputerType    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
 36 WinRM7          computerNam     RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          Busy
 37 WinRM4          computerNam     RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          Busy
 38 WinRM2          computerNam     RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          Busy
 39 WinRM5          computerNam     RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          Busy
 40 WinRM3          computerNam     RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          Busy
```

and piping `Disconnect-PSSession`...

```
PS C:\Users\username> Get-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential | Disconnect-PSSession

 Id Name            ComputerName    ComputerType    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
 46 WinRM7          computerNam     RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          Busy
 47 WinRM4          computerNam     RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          Busy
 48 WinRM2          computerNam     RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          Busy
 49 WinRM5          computerNam     RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          Busy
 50 WinRM3          computerNam     RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          Busy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Disconnect-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/disconnect-pssession?view=powershell-6) followed by [Remove-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-pssession?view=powershell-6):

```
Get-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential | Disconnect-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

> The Remove-PSSession cmdlet closes PowerShell sessions (PSSessions) in the current session. It stops any commands that are running in the PSSessions, ends the PSSession, and releases the resources that the PSSession was using. If the PSSession is connected to a remote computer, this cmdlet also closes the connection between the local and remote computers.

Comment: Weirdly enough I got a `Remove-PSSession : Cannot connect the PSSession because the session is not in the Disconnected state, or is not available for
connection.` while I do have working interactive PSSession open

Comment: Updated my answer, per the other answer try doing a disconnect first and then remove. I've not tested this but assuming that the disconnect cmdlet passes the object through.

Comment: `| Disconnect-PSSession | Remove-PSSession`

`Remove-PSSession : Cannot connect the PSSession because the session is not in the Disconnected state, or is not available for
connection.`

Comment: It would be worth running Get-PSSession on its own and looking at the output to see what the sessions are and what state they are in.

Comment: The issue looks to be occurring because the sessions all have an availability of "Busy", which means they are still running some command and can't be connected to. I can't see a way to work around this with the standard pssession cmdlets, but you could connect a new session to the remote machine and perhaps use it to terminate the powershell.exe processes via `get-process powershell | stop-process`.

Comment: How PowerShell knows to which device it should connect if multiple devices share the same IP address? If I am not mistaken, the `Enter-PSSession` cmd uses only the IP address as a parameter, not the device name or any other more specific addressing.

Answer (score 1):

From `get-help Exit-PSSession -full` I can see :

> Exit-PSSession [] ,  You cannot pipe objects to this
>   cmdlet.

What I think you are looking for is:

```
Get-PSSession | Disconnect-PSSession
```